# Java enum attributes returning null based on order of access

Tags: java, enums

I was exploring enums in java to see how they could be abused and I came across a behaviour I couldn't explain. Consider the following class:

```
public class PROGRAM {

public enum ENUM {;
    public enum ANIMALS {;
        public enum CATS {
            FELIX(DOGS.AKAME),
            GARFIELD(DOGS.WEED),
            BUBSY(DOGS.GIN);

            CATS(DOGS dog) {this.RIVAL = dog;}
            public DOGS RIVAL;
        }           
        public enum DOGS {
            GIN(CATS.FELIX), WEED(CATS.BUBSY), AKAME(CATS.GARFIELD);

            DOGS(CATS cat) {this.RIVAL = cat;}
            public CATS RIVAL;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ENUM.ANIMALS.CATS.GARFIELD.RIVAL);
    System.out.println(ENUM.ANIMALS.DOGS.GIN.RIVAL);
}
}
```

The first statement in the main function will print 'WEED', as expected. The second one will print 'null'. However, if you switch them around, i.e.

```
    System.out.println(ENUM.ANIMALS.DOGS.GIN.RIVAL);
    System.out.println(ENUM.ANIMALS.CATS.GARFIELD.RIVAL);
```

the first statement will print 'FELIX' and the second statement will now print 'null'. Is there anyone that can explain this phenomenon?

For reference, I'm running the Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with enums and class initialization.

First, `enum` is just a fancy `class` with constant fields. [That is, the enum constants you declare are in reality just `static` fields.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3) So

```
enum SomeEnum {
    CONSTANT;
}
```

compiles to something similar to

```
final class SomeEnum extends Enum<SomeEnum> {
    public static final SomeEnum CONSTANT = new SomeEnum();
}
```

Second, [`static` fields are initialized in the left to right order they appear in the source code.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static
>   initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
>   in textual order, as though they were a single block.

In the following

```
final class SomeEnum extends Enum<SomeEnum> {
    public static final SomeEnum CONSTANT = new SomeEnum();
    public static final SomeEnum CONSTANT_2 = new SomeEnum();
}
```

`CONSTANT` would be initialized first, and `CONSTANT_2` second.

Third, [an `enum` type will be [initialized][3] when you access one of its constants (which is really just a `static` field)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

Fourth, if a class is currently being initialized by the current thread, you proceed normally.

> If the `Class` object for `C` indicates that initialization is in progress
>   for `C` by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for
>   initialization. Release `LC` and complete normally.

How does this all come together?

This

```
ENUM.ANIMALS.CATS.GARFIELD.RIVAL
```

is evaluated like

```
CATS cat = ENUM.ANIMALS.CATS.GARFIELD;
DOGS rvial = cat.RIVAL;
```

The first access to `GARFIELD` forces the initialization of the `enum` type `CATS`. That begins initializing the enum constants in `CATS`. Compiled, those appear like

```
private static final CATS FELIX = new CATS(DOGS.AKAME);
private static final CATS GARFIELD = new CATS(DOGS.WEED);
private static final CATS BUBSY = new CATS(DOGS.GIN);
```

These get initialized in order. So `FELIX` goes first. As part of its new instance creation expression, it accesses `DOGS.AKAME`, where the type `DOGS` is not yet initialized, so Java starts initializing it. The `DOGS` enum type, compiled, looks like

```
private static final DOGS GIN = new DOGS(CATS.FELIX);
private static final DOGS WEED = new DOGS(CATS.BUBSY);
private static final DOGS AKAME = new DOGS(CATS.GARFIELD);
```

So we start with `GIN`. In its new instance creation expression, it tries to access `CATS.FELIX`. `CATS` is current being initialized, so we just continue. `CATS.FELIX` hasn't been assigned a value yet. It's currently in construction lower on the stack. So its value is `null`. So `GIN.RIVALS` gets a reference to `null`. The same happens to all `DOGS`' `RIVAL`.

When all of the `DOGS` are initialized, execution returns to

```
private static final CATS FELIX = new CATS(DOGS.AKAME);
```

where `DOGS.AKAME` now refers to a fully initialize `DOGS` object. That gets assigned to its `CATS#RIVAL` field. Same for each of the `CATS`. In other words, all the `CATS`' `RIVAL` field are assigned a `DOGS` reference, but not the other way around.

Reordering the statements simply determines which `enum` type gets initialized first.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ENUM.ANIMALS.CATS.GARFIELD.RIVAL`, it will start by creating the CATS enum. When processing the first element, FELIX, it needs to create the DOGS enum so that DOGS.AKAME can be passed as a parameter to the CATS constructor.

The DOGS constructor receives a parameter of type CATS, but since CATS was not yet initialized all CATS.something will return `null`, thus setting the RIVAL attribute to `null` for all elements in the DOGS enum.

When all DOGS elements are created, it goes back to CATS and resumes the creation of its elements, passing the just created DOGS elements as parameters.

Similarly, when you invert the order of the calls it starts by creating the DOGS enum which causes the CATS elements RIVAL attribute to be set as `null`.

If this is not clear, try to run your code with breakpoints set at the enum elements' declarations and at the constructors to understand it better.